# how to pass Material UI theme to many "routed" components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've seen a few uses of `withStyles` and `withTheme`, but I don't think they apply to `ReactDOM.render`. Is there a way to get my custom theme to be accessible from all components?

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({/*... lots of theme code here */});

const app = signalRConnection => (
  <SignalRProvider connection={signalRConnection}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={DashboardPage} />
        <Route path="/foo/:id" component={FooPage} />
        <Route path="/test" component={TestPage} />
        <Route path="/home/chat" component={ChatApp} />
        <Route render={() => <Redirect to="/" />} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  </SignalRProvider>
);

window.renderApp = function(id, signalRConnection) {
  ReactDOM.render(app(signalRConnection), document.getElementById(id));
};
```

Doing this seems like a hack, but I'm not sure if it is:

```
<Route
  path='/'
  component={() => <DashboardPage theme={theme} />}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MuiThemeProvider` makes the theme available to all the descendant components, so you don't need to do anything extra to make the theme available (your routes are all already descendants of `MuiThemeProvider`). You would use `withTheme` or `withStyles` in the component (e.g. `DashboardPage`) that needs to use the theme.

If you want to be able to access the theme as a prop within `DashboardPage` then `DashboardPage` could look something like:

```
import React from "react";
import { withTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
const DashboardPage = ({ theme }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Primary color is {theme.palette.primary.main}</div>
      <Button color="primary" variant="contained">
        Show Theme in a Button
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};
const DashboardPageWithTheme = withTheme()(DashboardPage);
export default DashboardPageWithTheme;
```

Here's a working example:

[image: Edit ywx1nvvy6z]